# Bind jQuery element break if the element is not found on the page?

Tags: jquery

what happens if the element I am binding jQuery code to is not found on the page? 
Does the previous binded code breaks?

Let me explain it with a sample. I have the following code inside my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.deleteMemo').live('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            [ajax call omitted for brevity]
        });
    });

    $('.markAsViewed').live('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            [ajax call omitted for brevity]
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, depending on the page status in the page there could be:

- Only elements with "deleteMemo" class
- Only elements with "markAsViewed" class
- Both

I am experimentig that, in the first case (only "deleteMemo" elements), the jQuery code does'nt get called at all. I still have not did a try with the other cases but I have triple checked the code and even looked at it with fiddler.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter if the elements are on the page when calling `.live()` because `.live()` does not bind the handler to the actual elements.

This is the purpose of using `.live()`. It allows elements that are dynamically added to the page to fire a handler that was added before they existed.

If any *ancestors* of a `.deleteMemo` (for example) stops event bubbling from taking place, then `live()` will not work for that element.

So if you have any click handlers on any of the ancestors that either have:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

or:

```
return false;
```

...in them, the `live()` handler will not fire.

Of course if the selector doesn't match (check capitalization for example) then the handler won't fire.

Comment: Great! there was a "return false" that in one case was executed. Thanks!